# vb.net Manually open a file while it is being written to

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net, is it possible to manually open and read a file while a program is writing to it?

I'd like the ability to open a text file (using notepad or other editor) to monitor the writing application's progress. We could do this with vb6. In vb.net I've tried this:

```
FileOpen(fileNum, logFilePath & logFileName, OpenMode.Append, OpenShare.Shared)
```

but even with it opened as shared, I still receive an access error when attempting to open the file:

> A sharing violation occurred while accessing file

Comment: Try opening the file in read mode.

Comment: Don't use `FileOpen()` in VB.Net. **EVER**.

Comment: Whats wrong with `FileOpen()`?

Comment: i know i have now edited the comment

Comment: See Remarks - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.fileopen.aspx

Comment: Its also good practice to avoid any backward compatibility functions carried over from VB6, and to use the .NET native element instead.

Comment: Which would be what?  I've tried using a streamwriter to create the file but it doesn't seem to post the data until the file is closed.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible as long as the file is not locked. When opening a file in your program, you can specify what kind of locking rules to use. If another program has a file open, you cannot control how that program opened the file. *Both* programs must agree to share the file for it to be shared, so if the other program used a mode that is not shared, you're stuck.

An example of how to open a file for writing that will allow sharing:

```
Using writeStream = File.Open("F:\ile.path", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite), _
      writer As New StreamWriter(writeStream)

    ' Use the file here

End Using
```

And then in another program:

```
'Same path as prior file.
Using readStream = File.Open("F:\ile.path", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), _
      reader As New StreamReader(readStream)

    ' Use the file here

End Using
```

Comment: Joel - In what way could I create the file (in the writing program) so it can be shared?  Again, I've tried fileOpen() and OpenShare.Shared (see original question) but it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks Joel!  I used your example and added:  'writer.autoflush = true' .  Now am getting the immediate results I was looking for.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this as a process. I am not exactly sure if this will work in your case, but it does not hurt to try:

```
Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process
Dim s As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:yourfile.txt")
s.UseShellExecute = True
s.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
p.StartInfo = s
p.Start()
```

Let me know if you have any errors and we can try to work through them.